ошибка python path при запуске pgadmin4
Для своего проекта скачал postgreSQL 14.11. Установил, создал супер юзера, создал базу данных, но при запуске pgadmin4 выходит ошибка:

The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:  pgAdmin Runtime
Environment
-------------------------------------------------------- Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe" Runtime
Config File:
"C:\Users\Татьяна\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json" pgAdmin
Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\web\pgAdmin4.py" pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program
Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program
Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py" Environment:

ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
APPDATA: C:\Users\Татьяна\AppData\Roaming
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \.\pipe\crashpad_4724_MXBYYWBNDQTUACUB
CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Произошел сбой NW.js. Перезапустить?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME: LAPTOP-0KI07I27
ComSpec: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING: Internet Explorer
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING: Default
HOMEDRIVE: C:
HOMEPATH: \Users\Татьяна
LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\Татьяна\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER: \LAPTOP-0KI07I27
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 2
OneDrive: C:\Users\Татьяна\OneDrive
OS: Windows_NT
Path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\runtime;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
Files (x86)\ATI
Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
Files\Git\cmd;C:\python\Scripts;C:\python;C:\Users\Татьяна\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2021.3.2\bin;C:\Users\Татьяна\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\scripts;;C:\Program
Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\bin;
PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PGADMIN_INT_KEY: a9282a05-877c-448d-9510-82b19051e7a5
PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 53806
PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: AMD64 Family 22 Model 48 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 22
PROCESSOR_REVISION: 3001
ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
PyCharm Community Edition: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\bin;
SESSIONNAME: Console
SystemDrive: C:
SystemRoot: C:\WINDOWS
TEMP: C:\Users\8C74~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP: C:\Users\8C74~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN: LAPTOP-0KI07I27
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: LAPTOP-0KI07I27
USERNAME: Татьяна
USERPROFILE: C:\Users\Татьяна
VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE: 1
windir: C:\WINDOWS


Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.101 Sec 2024-04-03
11:45:57,635: ERROR   pgadmin:    Database migration failed
2024-04-03 11:45:57,713: ERROR    pgadmin:    Traceback (most recent call
last):   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in
_exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in
do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: connection_params
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 374, in
upgrade_db
db_upgrade(app)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_upgrade.py", line 22, in db_upgrade
flask_migrate.upgrade(migration_folder)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_migrate_init_.py", line 111, in
wrapped
f(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_migrate_init_.py", line 200, in
upgrade
command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 403, in upgrade
script.run_env()   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 583, in
run_env
util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in
load_python_file
module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in
load_module_py
spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "", line 940, in exec_module   File
"", line 241, in
call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\web\pgadmin\setup....\migrations\env.py", line 95, in 
run_migrations_online()   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\web\pgadmin\setup....\migrations\env.py", line 87, in
run_migrations_online
context.run_migrations()   File "", line 8, in run_migrations   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 948,
in run_migrations
self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 627, in
run_migrations
step.migration_fn(**kw)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\web\migrations\versions\f656e56dfdc8.py", line 111, in upgrade
migrate_connection_params('server')   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\web\migrations\versions\f656e56dfdc8_.py", line 32, in
migrate_connection_params
op.add_column(table_name,   File "", line 8, in add_column   File "", line 3, in add_column   File "C:\Program
Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\ops.py", line 2142, in
add_column
return operations.invoke(op)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\base.py", line 445, in
invoke
return fn(self, operation)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\toimpl.py", line 171, in
add_column
operations.impl.add_column(table_name, column, schema=schema, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 334, in
add_column
self._exec(base.AddColumn(table_name, column, schema=schema))   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 207, in _exec
return conn.execute(construct, multiparams)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416, in
execute
return meth(
^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 181, in
_execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_ddl(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1528, in
_execute_ddl
ret = self._execute_context(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1848, in
_execute_context
return self._exec_single_context(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1988, in
_exec_single_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2344, in
_handle_dbapi_exception
raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in
_exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in
do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate
column name: connection_params [SQL: ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN
connection_params JSON] (Background on this error at:
https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in
_exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in
do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: connection_params
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 374, in
upgrade_db
db_upgrade(app)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_upgrade.py", line 22, in db_upgrade
flask_migrate.upgrade(migration_folder)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_migrate_init_.py", line 111, in
wrapped
f(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_migrate_init_.py", line 200, in
upgrade
command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 403, in upgrade
script.run_env()   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 583, in
run_env
util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in
load_python_file
module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in
load_module_py
spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "", line 940, in exec_module   File
"", line 241, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\web\pgadmin\setup....\migrations\env.py", line 95, in 
run_migrations_online()   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\web\pgadmin\setup....\migrations\env.py", line 87, in
run_migrations_online
context.run_migrations()   File "", line 8, in run_migrations   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 948,
in run_migrations
self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 627, in
run_migrations
step.migration_fn(**kw)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\web\migrations\versions\f656e56dfdc8_.py", line 111, in upgrade
migrate_connection_params('server')   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\web\migrations\versions\f656e56dfdc8_.py", line 32, in
migrate_connection_params
op.add_column(table_name,   File "<string>", line 8, in add_column   File "<string>", line 3, in add_column   File "C:\Program

Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\ops.py", line 2142, in
add_column
return operations.invoke(op)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\base.py", line 445, in
invoke
return fn(self, operation)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\toimpl.py", line 171, in
add_column
operations.impl.add_column(table_name, column, schema=schema, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 334, in
add_column
self._exec(base.AddColumn(table_name, column, schema=schema))   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 207, in _exec
return conn.execute(construct, multiparams)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416, in
execute
return meth(

       ^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 181, in

_execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_ddl(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1528, in
_execute_ddl
ret = self._execute_context(
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1848, in
_execute_context
return self._exec_single_context(

       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1988, in
_exec_single_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin

4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2344, in
_handle_dbapi_exception
raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e

File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in
_exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(

File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in
do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate
column name: connection_params [SQL: ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN
connection_params JSON] (Background on this error at:
https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 104, in 
app = create_app()
^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 461, in create_app
run_migration_for_sqlite()   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 420, in

run_migration_for_sqlite
upgrade_db()
File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin
4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 379, in upgrade_db
backup_db_file()   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 356, in backup_db_file
os.rename(SQLITE_PATH, backup_file_name) PermissionError: [WinError 32] ������� �� ����� �������� ������ � �����, ��� ��� ����

���� ����� ������ ���������:
'C:\Users\�������\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.db' ->
'C:\Users\�������\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.db.20240403114557'

